# C# Printing 8.5x11 pages to 11x17 booklets

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am having a problem with a program to print documents for a client.  The original files contain pages that are 8.5x11 landscape.  I need to print into 11x17 booklet.

I can generate pages - mostly in correct order - but I get pages that are flipped.

I think  I am having problems when I need to add extra blank pages onto the output document so I get an even number of SHEETS from a number of PAGES that is less than the pages per sheet to meet the SHEET requirements.

4 pages = 1 sheet.  17 pages = 4 sheets + 1 page.  I need to output 5 sheets with the first page and last page on the same side of SHEET 1,

I just need a little push in getting the math correct for getting the pages out correctly.

Client sends a file that has 17 (or 18, 22, 27) pages.  I need to be certain that the middle pages are in the middle and the first and last page are on the outside cover page.

```
using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(rec.DirName + @"\" + rec.FileName + ".pdf"))
using (Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(792, 1224)))
using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document,
        new FileStream(outputPath + rec.SequenceNumber.ToString("D5") + "_" + outFname[0] + "_" + outFname[1] + ".pdf",
        FileMode.Create)))
{
    int lastPage = 0;
    pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
    document.Open();

    var content = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

    // Determine the last page and ensure there is an even amount.
    if (rec.PageCount > 8 && rec.PageCount <= 12) // pages 9, 10, 11, and 12
    {
        lastPage = 12;
        ++_3SheetCount;
    }
    else if (rec.PageCount > 12 && rec.PageCount <= 16) // pages 13, 14, 15, and 16
    {
        lastPage = 16;
        ++_4SheetCount;
    }
    else if (rec.PageCount > 16 && rec.PageCount <= 20) // pages 17, 18, 19, and 20
    {
        lastPage = 20;
        ++_5SheetCount;
    }
    else if (rec.PageCount > 20 && rec.PageCount <= 24) // pages 21, 22, 23, and 24
    {
        lastPage = 24;
        ++_6SheetCount;
    }
    else if (rec.PageCount > 24 && rec.PageCount <= 28) // pages 25, 26, 27, and 28
    {
        lastPage = 28;
        ++_7SheetCount;
    }
    else if (rec.PageCount >28 && rec.PageCount <=32) // pages 29, 30, 31, and 32
    {
        lastPage = 32;
        ++_8SheetCount;
    }

    // Iterate to the middle sheet.
    // Count up from the first page and down from the last page
    for (int i = 1, j = lastPage; i <= lastPage / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        // Front side layout is: | J | I |
        // Back side layout is:  | I | J |
        int iy = (i % 2 == 1) ? 0 : 612;
        int jy = (i % 2 == 1) ? 612 : 0;

        document.NewPage();

        // Add the I page.
        content.AddTemplate(pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i), 0, iy);

        // process address block, IMB and 2D
        #region Address, 2D, IMB and Permit

        if (i == 1)
        {
            // print mailing address information here 
        }

        #endregion

        // if the J page does not exist in the original PDF then leave it blank.
        if (j <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages)
            content.AddTemplate(pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, j), 0, jy);

        ++sheetCountTotal;
    }

    document.Close();
    pdfWriter.Close();
}
```

Comment: Closed!  

Turns out the problem was at the stage of moving the properly produced PDF to the physical printer using a virtual printer to set some print preferences that were then being overridden by the physical printer hold queue settings.